# Best Self-Hosting Solution for TFS 2010?

Tags: virtualization, vmware, virtualbox, virtual-pc

I want to install **TFS 2010** on my own machine - *a Dell Laptop with 8GB RAM*, running *Windows 7*. Now, since installing on Win7 means I *can't run SharePoint or Reports*, and I don't want to reformat my machine to Win 2008, I need to virtualize.

I would like something that I can have always on, and treat like a server on my LAN, or at the very least, something that I can activate quickly, when needed. Oh, and I'd like it to be free :).

As far as I can tell, my options are **MS Virtual PC, Virtual Box, VMWare**.

What would be my best option? Are there any other options?

Thanks,
Assaf

Comment: you can run SharePoint 2010 in win 7...

Comment: True, but not Windows Sharepoint Services (which TFS uses), AFAIK. The TFS 2010 installation on client OSes won't install WSS or SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use MS Virtual PC or VMWare. I have been using TFS2010 installed on MS Virtual PC and its working fine.

Comment: Is there any visible performance, size or reliability difference between the two? Is there a reason you didn't mention Virtual Box, or did you just not try it? I'd like to take the best performing solution.

Comment: I haven't tried out the Virtual box and i didn't find any major difference between the two but I think VMWare Would be better. I preferred Virtual PC, because I also run other Pre-configured VPC images released by Microsoft.

Comment: Does VMWare have a free solution? I don't intend to run production servers or anything - just host a server instance on my laptop for my own use.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like this is my solution!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use 8 GB RAM, you'll want to use either VMWare or repave your machine (but save the TFS databases) as Windows Server 2008 R2 and use Hyper-V.

You can then install TFS 2010 again but point it at your set of restored databases.  You'll be able to enable the SharePoint and Reporting for your newly restored TFS instance.

Comment: Hן Ed, I'm less looking for a "how to" solve the problem, but more of a "what should I do". I guess it boils down to which solution is best, and why.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran it on a VM from my Dev box and the performance wasn't the best. Memory and disk IO are very important when running SQL and the competition with multiple instances of Visual Studio, plus the overhead of VMWare made it unbearable. With enough memory and RAID or a SSD, you may be okay.

I know it's not free, but there are a few hosted solutions that are decently priced ([TFS Server Hosting](http://www.tfsserver.com)). They also allow you to access it from anywhere and your code will be backed up.

Comment: Thanks for the input about VM - were you talking about VMs in general, or VMWare? Anyway, I've got a TFS server at work - I'm looking for one to host on **my own** laptop - for testing, tweaking, and customization development, so I really need my own TFS instance to be able to trash with abandon... That's why I'm looking to find a local virtual solution.

Comment: Mine was specifically VMWare, but I would expect the same result from Hyper-V.

I think Microsoft has a vhd that you can use to test it out with Hyper-V on your laptop.

Comment: You should mention in each of your answers where you suggest your own service/software that it's your own product.